# Load Unity3D file in Xamarin WebView

Tags: unity-game-engine, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, unity-web-player

I'm trying to integrate Unity3D game into Xamarin using Xamarin Forms WebView Control.

I have an output from unity (unity web player file) .html + .unity3d files.

I placed files in android 'assets/unity/' directory.

Created webview control in xamarin forms and named it as browser.

Loading html file from 'assets/unity' directory.

Look below for my code

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        browser.Source = "file:///android_asset/Unity/Sample_Web.html";

    }
}
```

Output is displayed as : [image]

Output is not as expected. I assume it is missing unity web player plugin. Can anyone suggest how to load unity web player file in xamarin forms webview ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it showing anything when you set Google as a source? Maybe the `WebView` isn't shown at all? Or is the label at the top from the page as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser does not support web player. To be sure, try opening some other web player game.

An alternative is to use [Three.js](https://threejs.org/)